# multiline grep search into separate files per occurence

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I have a file as following:

***example.txt***

```
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1
 
#ffafsda
    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
    
    asfasd
    
    afsdasdf
```

It consists of blocks always starting and ending by line entirely matching `^ {4}-1$`.
I need to separate a file into multiple by these blocks.

What I figured out right now is this multiline regex that extracts these blocks:

`grep -Pzo '(?s)((?m:^)\s{4}-1(?m:$).*?(?m:^)\s{4}-1(?m:$))' example.txt`

output:

```
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
```

You see second match is exactly printed behind first match (no newline or separator) - I'm failing to separate these occurences into files

required output is following:

***file1:***

```
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1
```

***file2***

```
    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How should the files be named?

Comment: can be current file basename with a counter for each occurence

Comment: When you say "line entirely matching `^\s{4}-1$`", do you actually mean `^ {4}-1$` (i.e. exactly 4 _spaces_) or do you really mean any 4 characters in the `\s` class (tabs, newlines, vertical tabs, carriage returns etc)?

Comment: Also, what output should be in the files? Can you show the output you would want from your example? Should the `-1` lines be included? You only show the failed output so I am not sure what the good output would look like.

Comment: Please fix your example data. If the file does start with the `    -1` header, that changes the approaches we can use significantly. If you don't give a representative input example then we will waste your time and ours giving solutions that don't work for you.

Comment: corrected for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Another method to get whole blocks instead of `grep`

First, I suggest to use `sed` to create the

```
sed -n '/^ \{4\}-1$/,/^ \{4\}-1$/p' example.txt
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1
    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
```

#### Splitting blocks to different files

Then you can use [`csplit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) command to split the file according to the pattern.

> **NAME**
>
> `csplit` - split a file into sections determined by context lines
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> `csplit` [OPTION]... FILE PATTERN...
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Output pieces of FILE separated by PATTERN(s) to files 'xx00', 'xx01', ..., and output byte counts of each piece to standard output.

#### Example

```
$ sed -n '/^ \{4\}-1$/,/^ \{4\}-1$/p' example.txt | csplit - -f example --suppress-matched -z '/^ \{4\}-1$/' '{*}'
331
292
```

Explanation:

- `csplit -` - will read from standard input
- `-f example` - sets the prefix of the files to "example" (instead of the default "xx". Each prefix will be followed by a two digit number starting from 00.
- `--suppress-matched` - suppress the lines matching the pattern (`/^ \{4\}-1$/`).

  - It's needed because `csplit` performs the split by the pattern (you can't tell it the first and the last line, only a pattern), so after each "closing" pattern it will create a file just with the pattern (because in the following it will be split again). If you surpress the pattern, you could avoid this by the next flag:
- `-z` - remove empty output file
- `'/^ \{4\}-1$/'` - the pattern indicates where to split the file.
- `'{*}'` - repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible

It will output the size of each file it creates.

Result: 2 files with the required blocks, but without the pattern.

```
$ cat example00
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000

$ cat example01
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
```

If you want to return the separator lines to the file (    `-1` in the first and last line), you can use the following command:

```
sed -i '1s/.*/    -1\n\0/; $s/$/\n    -1/' example[0-9][0-9]
```

#### Further explanation about `--suppress-matched` and `-z` flags

To explain the need for `--suppress-matched`, I'll show you what happens

```
$ sed -n '/^ \{4\}-1$/,/^ \{4\}-1$/p' example.txt | csplit -f example  -z - '/^ \{4\}-1$/' '{*}'
338
7
299
7
```

It created 4 files. Notice that `example01` and `example03` only include the pattern.

```
$ cat example00
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000

$ cat example01
    -1

$ cat example02
    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23

$ cat example03
    -1
```

When using the `--suppress-matched`, the lines with -1 will be suppressed, and the result would be that `example01` and `example03` would be empty and thus will not be created.

Comment: You could store the regexp in a variable so you don't have to repeat it 3 times since duplicate code is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

With `-z` (a non-standard GNU extension), `grep` works on NUL delimited records, it's not *multiline grep*¹, so:

- the matching is done on each NUL-delimited record independently or the whole input if not delimited (the ability to work with non-delimited records is another GNU extension)
- with `-o` (another non-standard GNU extension) each match is output NUL-delimited

So the records in your output **are** separated (actually *delimited*). Which you can see if you pass the output through `sed -n l` for instance:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)((?m:^)\s{4}-1(?m:$).*?(?m:^)\s{4}-1(?m:$))' example.txt | sed -n l
    -1$
    15$
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1\
.0000E+001$
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1\
.0000E+001$
...$
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1\
.0000E+001$
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5\
.0000E+000$
    -1\000    -1$
    780$
         1       116         1         2         1         1         \
7        20$
         1        11         2        15         4        18         \
3        12$
        13        16        22        19         5        24         \
9        29$
         8        27         6        23$
    -1\000$
```

See the `\000`s that delimits each match.

Here you could simplify your matching with:

```
grep -Pzo '(?sm)(^\s{4}-1$).*?(?1)' example.txt
```

But rather that using `grep` with that `-P` (for `P`erl, also a non-standard GNU extension), you could use the real thing which would have several advantages:

- be more portable as perl is present on more systems than GNU grep is (and perl-like regexp support is not always enabled at build time in GNU `grep`)
- perl has `-0` to work with NUL-delimited records, but that's not what you want here. You want a slurp mode which in `perl` is with `-0777`
- perl can write the output to separate files by itself:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne '
  while (/(^\s{4}-1$).*?(?1)/msg) {
    open OUT, ">", "output-" . ++$n . ".txt" or die;
    print OUT $&
  }' example.txt
```

Or rather than slurping the file as a whole and use regexps, read it line by line:

```
perl -ne '
  if (/^\s{4}-1$/) {
    if ($inside = 1 - $inside) {
      open OUT, ">", "output-" . ++$n . ".txt" or die;
    } else {
      print OUT; next
    }
  }
  print OUT if $inside' example.txt
```

(though it would given a different outcome if the `-1` were not all matched).

---

<sup>¹ for that, see `pcre2grep -M` (formerly `pcregrep -M`), `pcre2grep` being an example application shipped with PCRE2 which GNU `grep` uses (can use) for its `-P` option.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU awk, which allows for regular expressions to be used as the record separator, as the thing that defines "lines". Here, we can set that as `\n    -1\n`, so a newline, 4 spaces, `-1` and a newline. Then, since this appears at the start and end of the sections you want, we essentially want every second "line", so we can print when the line number modulo 2 is 0:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN{
    RS="\n    -1\n"; 
    ORS=RS
  } 
  NR % 2 ==0 { print RS $0 > "outfile." ++c }' file
```

Running the above on your example produced two files with the following contents:

```
$ ls
file  outfile.1  outfile.2
$ cat outfile.1

    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1
$ cat outfile.2

    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
```

This does have the unfortunate side-effect of adding a blank line to the beginning of each file. If that is a problem, you could just print the     `-1` explicitly instead:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN{
    RS="\n    -1\n"; 
  } 
  NR % 2 ==0 { printf "   -1\n%s\n    -1\n", $0 > "outfile." ++c }' file
```

Comment: I also thought about it, the only problem is if the file begins with `    -1` and there's no new line before it, or if it ends with one without a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: Yeah, I know @aviro but the OP's example does seem to have other text in the beginning. And, strictly speaking, a text file requires a newline as the last character or it isn't a text file, so I figured those two limitations were OK and I couldn't resist playing with `RS` this way :)

Comment: In my case it will directly start with "    -1" (without initial "\n"). I  haven't specify it. But still your answer is quite educational.

Comment: @HonzaS. Then please edit your question and make sure the example input is correct.

Comment: You could change `RS="\n    -1\n"` to `RS="(^|\n)    -1\n"` to solve the problem of a record at the start of the file and change `print RS $0` to `print gensub(/^\n/,"",1,RS) $0` to solve the problem of a blank line at the start of each output file.

Comment: Or use a second variable,`BEGIN{ rbeg="    -1\n"; RS="(^|\n)"rbeg } ... { print rbeg $0 }`

Answer (score 0):

If it were me:

```
gawk '/^\s{4}-1$/ { X=X+1 } { print $0 >> ( "outfile" X ) }' <inputfile
```

Comment: i) that doesn't run, it complains about `fatal: expression for \`>>' redirection has null string value` since `outfile` isn't set (did you mean `"outfile"`?). ii) that would print everything, not only the parts between two `\s{4}-1`s.

Comment: No, its complaining because you are feeding it input which doesn't begin with the "header" and X is unset. If you insert a `BEGIN { X=0}` at the front of the awk expression it will work fine with content which does not begin with the header. (OP stated "consists of blocks always starting and ending by line entirely matching ^\s{4}-1$")

Comment: We have the example input. It isn't _only_ those blocks, that seems to be what the OP is trying to extract. And what do you mean about header? I just posted the OP's code into a file and ran the exact command in your answer to get the error I reported. And it makes sense: you are using a variable named `outfile` but never give it a value, which is what the error complains about. What am I missing? Or did you mean to use `"outfile"` as I suggested before?

Comment: Yes, "outfile" should be quoted

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes more sense. You're still assuming the entire file's contents are desired though. Please try this on the example in the OP (and, in general, do try to execute your code at least once, you would have noticed the error) and you will see that it includes text that should not be in the output.

Comment: `print $0 >> ( "outfile" X )` should be `print $0 > ( "outfile" X )`. Awks semantics for `print >` and `>>` aren't quite the same as shell. `awk '{print > "foo"}'` is equivalent to shell `while read line; do echo "$line"; done > foo`, not `while read line; do echo "$line" > foo; done` and `awk '{print >> "foo"}'` is equivalent to shell `while read line; do echo "$line"; done >> foo` (note you'd need to prepend that shell loop with `>foo` to zap it). As written your script would keep appending to existing output files each time it's run instead of starting over on each execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^    -1/ {
    if ( inBlock ) {
        print > out; close(out)
    }
    else {
        out = FILENAME "_" (++cnt)
    }
    inBlock = !inBlock
}
inBlock { print > out }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk example.txt
```

```
$ head example.txt_*
==> example.txt_1 <==
    -1
    15
         1         0         0        11 -1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
         2         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  1.0000E+001 -1.0000E+001
...
        29         0         0        11  1.0000E+001  2.0000E+001  1.0000E+001
        30         0         0        11  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000  5.0000E+000
    -1

==> example.txt_2 <==
    -1
    780
         1       116         1         2         1         1         7        20
         1        11         2        15         4        18         3        12
        13        16        22        19         5        24         9        29
         8        27         6        23
    -1
```